# Why does my Unity animator state "finish" before the visible motion does?

Tags: unity, animation, state

***Example:***

The TopAppearing motion -  boost the alpha of the sprite from 0 to 1 for total of 2 seconds:

[image]

After TopAppearing state has been finished:

[image]

The TopAppearing's transition settings:

### [image]

**Question:**

- Why is the Top's sprite alpha 235 after the TopAppearing animatior state has been finished?

Answer (score 1):

This is an official bug in Unity Mecanim , similar problem posted on the unity forum http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/exit-time-of-1-but-animation-exits-before-finishing-full-example-included.319205/ . They have said that it will be fixed in Unity 5.2 , I currently have Unity 5.1 so can't confirm.

A quick and dirty fix in your case will be to change the "Transition Duration (%)" to 0.75

Comment: Thanks but if I make the duration 0, the TopAppearing stops as soon as the transition starts. In other words when the TopTextAppearing starts the TopAppearing stops. Unless I am missing anything?

You can try it yourself, there is a template package of the problem isolated. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8abuw11ylt0o1lu/tmp.unitypackage?dl=0

Comment: Change your exit time to 2

Comment: This is most likely gonna work but that's not the point. The idea is the TopTextAppearing to start on half of the execution of TopAppearing. If I set the Exit Time to 2, the TopTextAppearing is going to start a lot after the TopAppearing motion has finished.

Comment: got it ..let me try some things out